# how to change filtered href link?

Tags: php, html, regex, filtering

I have an `<iframe>` embed link :

```
<iframe src="https://mixlr.com/users/2229015/embed" width="100%" height="180px" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
</iframe>

<small>
    <a href="https://mixlr.com/radio-tooba" style="color:#1a1a1a;text-align:left; font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:11px;">Radio Tooba is on Mixlr</a>
</small>
```

But the `src` and `href` are blocked in my country!
I want to avoid filtering and show this embed code on my web site.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Its not blocked for everyone, just use a VPN and work around the block. Though you could proxy it, in code (php is not ideal), edge worker (cloudflare etc) or using a reverse proxy on your webserver, either way, you inherit the additional usage overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You could pull the contents of the `iframe` on the backend, like with PHP with something like `curl` or `file_get_contents()`, and even utilize proxy within the backend to go around the blockage.. and once you have the content, render it on your website where needed.